# Objective C: How to get another application's bundle identifier

Tags: objective-c, bundle, identifier

I would like to get the bundle identifier of an application, given it's path.

eg:

```
NSString* vlcFilePath =  @"/Applications/VLC.app"
```

I know how to get the bundle identifier using `NSWorkspace` if it is the active application, but in this case it is not necessarily the active application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NSBundle has a [`bundleIdentifier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIJAJFF) method. This won't run or load the application if it is not already loaded/running:

```
NSString *vlcFilePath = @"/Applications/VLC.app";

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:vlcFilePath];

NSLog (@"%@", [bundle bundleIdentifier]);
```

Comment: That's short and sweet, what if I want it directly from .ipa instead of .app file, is there a way to get it, I don't want to zip and then open the payload and then get the .app file.

Answer (score -2):

Open the application bundle's plist file and read it from there:

```
NSDictionary *plistInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[vlcPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/Info.plist"]];

NSLog(@"VLC bundle identifier = %@", [plistInfo objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]);
```

Comment: Bad idea. The Info.plist can be stored in other locations. Using bundle APIs is much more robust.

Comment: In particular, this won't work for applications which store their Info.plist in a special section of the binary, or applications using the flat bundle layout. You should generally treat NSBundle as being an opaque directory format and access it via its API only.